# Android widget and two different PendingIntents

Tags: android

Here's what I'm trying to achieve:
Widget with 3 buttons:
1. View folder
2. Add item
3. Add item and start a camera to attach a photo to the item.

I was hoping to achieve 2&3 by using an Intent with extras, just add a boolean extra "photo" to hold true if the 3rd button was clicked, here's my code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("content://"
                + NoteProviderMetaData.AUTHORITY + "/folders/"
                + folderId));
intent.putExtra("photo", false);
intent.putExtra("kind", "NO PHOTO");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imageButton2, pendingIntent);

Intent intentFolder = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intentFolder.setData(Uri.parse("content://"
                + NoteProviderMetaData.AUTHORITY + "/folders/"
                + folderId + "/notes"));
PendingIntent pendingIntentFolder = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intentFolder, 0);
Intent intentPhoto = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
intentPhoto.setData(Uri.parse("content://"
        + NoteProviderMetaData.AUTHORITY + "/folders/"
                + folderId));
intentPhoto.putExtra("photo", true);
intentPhoto.putExtra("kind", "PHOTO");
intentPhoto.setAction(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
PendingIntent pendingIntentPhoto = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intentPhoto, 0);
views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imageButton3, pendingIntentPhoto);
```

The problem is that immediately after I create `pendingIntentPhoto` my `pendingIntent` extras are overridden by new values and I always get `true` and `PHOTO` values in my activity.
`pendingFolder` intent works, so I guess it would be fine just to use another intent action but I'd like to understand how this PendingIntent thing works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to achieve this using this method's undocumented feature:

`public static PendingIntent getActivity (Context context, int requestCode, Intent intent, int flags)`

From the docs:
`requestCode    Private request code for the sender (currently not used).`

Apparently this code is currently used somehow. Supplying different requestCodes to this method calls allowed me to create different `PendingIntents` for the same widget.